# what happens if a taskmagaer pod is restarted

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I use EKS Cluster and node groups to set up my Flink Cluster. When a node group scales down, some nodes are removed and taskmanager pods(actually k8s deployment) are re-deployed in another node.

Although flink restarts whole job based on its latest checkpoint, some data is duplicated as the checkpoint does not contain excatly last state.

I tried to look for the option to get rid of the duplication but could not find.
Is there any flink option for k8s?

Comment: Can yo provide more context by what you mean by "some data is duplicated"? Where/how are you seeing this duplicated data?

Comment: @kkrugler 
The flink job moves data from topic A to topic B in kafka. As the checkpoint does not contain excatly last state, when flink job is restarted, there is duplicated in topics B. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

When your job restarts, Flink will replay data from the source Kafka topic, beginning with the saved offset(s) from the last checkpoint. To avoid having downstream consumers see duplicate data in the output Kafka topic, you need to do the following in your Flink job:

- Enable Flink checkpointing with mode EXACTLY_ONCE
- Set DeliveryGuarantee.EXACTLY_ONCE on your Kafka Sink
- Set a transactional id prefix for Kafka Sink

And in downstream KafkaConsumers, set the `isolation.level` to `read_committed`. To be really sure, you also need to enable high availability (HA) mode for the JobManager. See https://ververica.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013269680-Best-Practices-for-Using-Kafka-Sources-Sinks-in-Flink-Jobs for even more steps to take.